# Reconstruction of registry.db of Macports

Tags: macports

When installing a package by using macports, my macbook did kernel panic.
After kernel panic, my macports told "macports registry malformed".
Therefore, I deleted "/opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db", and reinstall macports. So, packages are installed in /opt/local/ and cannot reinstall these package by macports, but my macports registry doesn't have a database of installed package.

How to make registry.db?

(My Mac OSX is El Capitan)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to reconstruct a `registry.db`. You should not have deleted the database.

Sometimes after a crash, the registry state can be recovered from the journal log if the registry is opened with write access, but this will not work if you deleted it.

Your only option at this point is to follow the uninstall instructions at https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling and re-install all your ports.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
If happen same in next time, I'll be careful not to delete registry.